# generating a code by using sprintf in PHP

Tags: php

I want to generate a serial key with this pattern :

```
DA-7470-20762
```

and this is what I have done so far :

```
$code = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(microtime(true), true)));
$uuid = sprintf("%02s-%04o-%04o",
    $code[0].$code[1],
    $code[2].$code[3].$code[4].$code[5],
    $code[6].$code[7].$code[8].$code[9]
);
```

But I want to prevent serial keys like this :

```
AB-0000-0001
```

I need to remove all 0's, because they are so predictive.

Is there a way to set range for octal sprintf like `[1-9]`?

Comment: `0` is as predictive as any other number.

Comment: For a "serial key", wouldn't you want something with more logic and less randomness?

Comment: @deceze what do you suggest ? I generate at least 5000 of these random serial keys and after that we have user's PC unique Id , then I have a plan to mix this serial key with that UID and give him a password  (with a pattern).

Comment: Well, I don't know what your logic is, but if you want to guarantee that your keys are unique, you'll need to `do { /* generate */ } while (!unique($key))`, which may be wasteful, depending on how many of these you need to generate. Some logic that churns these out in sequential order may be of more use.

Comment: octal sprintf like [1-9] :) Octal would be [0-7] for a start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go with something along these lines:

```
printf('%2s-%4o-%4o',
       chr(mt_rand(65, 70)) . chr(mt_rand(65, 70)),
       mt_rand(01000, 07777),
       mt_rand(01000, 07777));
```

Comment: nice , but this is the output of your printf : YU-6367-147512
  as you can see in last section we have 6 digits and sum of chars are more than 10 chars. It should be 4 digits

Comment: Well yes, you were probably using octal formatting on decimal numbers. Changed my example to stay within A-F and 0-7 limits.

Comment: just I changed printf in your code with sprintf and now its a 10 digits serial key DB-5617-3001

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a way to minimise zeros, you could opt for a pre-serial-generation modification along the lines of the following pseudo-code:

```
for each idx in 2, 4, 6 and 8:
    if code[idx] == "0":
        code [idx] = randomNumBetween("1","7")
```